# Flutterflow: Can't copy drawer from one page to another

Tags: flutter, frontend, flutterflow

I am trying to copy and paste a drawer from one page to another but it copies the wrong widget.

When i copy and then paste the drawer in the other page, it simply pastes some icon instead of the drawer.

I hope someone can help :/

Comment: In order to help, we would need to some the source code and an if possible an image of what is going wrong

Answer (score 3):

Had the same need! This worked for me: right click on drawer (the one you want to copy), and select "Save as Template". Then in the other pages that you need to include it you can just add it as a template from your widget template list. It comes with all it has inside, including components and actions.